# Symfony Version 6.3.3 and php 8.2.4 incompatiblity for symfony/orm-pack

Tags: php, symfony, orm, composer-php

I have php 8.2.4 and I am working with symfony 6.3.3.

When i run the command

composer require symfony/orm-pack

it throws an error

- symfony/orm-pack[v1.0.0, ..., v1.0.7] require php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.2.4) does not satisfy that requirement.

Is there a method to resolve this issue without downgrading php version.
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOD1S.png)

I have tried multiple google searches to no avail.

Comment: Is it an issue or is it a requirement? And don't try google search, try this: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md - Start with general, then find your issue if not yet solved.

Comment: And it's not the PHP version, symfony/orm-pack requires fine with PHP 8.2.5 and the like ... why not look for why-not?

Comment: Which PHP version do you run Composer with?

Comment: I am using the composer version version 2.5.8

Answer (score 0):

composer require symfony/orm-pack -W

Causes composer to run taking into account package dependencies

There are times when requesting a package, only the package is received with certain dependencies that are not compatible with the project. The -W flag allows it to take all dependencies into account

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked like a wonder, could you explain what the -W does?

Comment: Causes composer to run taking into account package dependencies.

Comment: There are times when requesting a package, only the package is received with certain dependencies that are not compatible with the project. The -W flag allows it to take all dependencies into account.

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your answer** by editing it